# png-24 and Browser Support

Tags: browser, png, png-24

Should I use png-8 or png-24 in my website? Do most websites still use png-8 or is browser support good enough that I can safely use png-24? I have some jquery sliders, I don't know if that makes any difference or not.

Comment: But as minitech told in his answer I would also recommend to use png24. You just have to be aware not use the alpha channel if you want to target ie6

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Browser support is good enough that you can use PNG-24. IE6 even supports PNG-24.

If you're using the images for sliders, though, you'll probably want transparency and PNG-32 is supported by every modern browser as well. IE6 can display them, albeit without the proper transparency (unless you use hacks.)

Comment: Huh? png24 supports transparency and ie6 didn't support this. There is no full support for png24. Trnsparency will be ignored.

Comment: 24-bit PNGs (which I *thought* "PNG-24" meant, maybe not) don't support actual transparency...

Comment: You can store a alpha channel in a png24. And if you want to show this in ie 6 you need a js hack. But for sure the ie6 can display png24, but not all channels.

Comment: That's what I said about PNG-32, but are you sure PNG-24's transparency is not just keyed? Can you use multiple levels of alpha, not just transparent and fully opaque?

Comment: Sorry if I don't make it clear: you are right about this, but the ie6 didn't support this one alpha channel and use grey instead. So the ie6 has no full support for png24. That's all what I want say.